# Processing Tiff and saving to Django ImageField

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library, tiff

The program I'm trying to write takes in a multipage Tif file/stack and processes it by:

1. Changing tiffile to numpy arrays
2. Taking numpy arrays and turns them into tensors
3. Processes tensors and turns them back to numpy arrays
4. Finally takes said numpy arrays and turns it back into a tiff stack.

My Code: 
models.py :

```
from django.db import models
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile


from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile


# Create your models here.
class TiffModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=450)
    image = models.ImageField(blank = True, null = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def img (self):
        return self.image

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        images = []
        tensors = []
        processedArrays = []

        tiffStack = []
        
        # Read tif, convert each page into arrays in images[]
        for i in range(img.n_frames):
            img.seek(i)
            images.append(np.array(img))

        # Read every numpy array, convert to tensorflow, process by dividing by 2
        for x in images:
            tensorX = tf.convert_to_tensor(x)
            processedTensor = tf.math.divide(tensorX,2)
            tensors.append(processedTensor)

        # Convert back to numpy array
        for x in tensors:
            processedArrays.append(x.numpy())

        # Convert to tif
        for x in processedArrays:
            tiffStack.append(Image.fromarray(x))

        img = tiffStack[0].save(self.name + ".tiff", compression="tiff_deflate", save_all=True,
               append_images=tiffStack[1:])

        img.save(self)
```

The issue I'm running into is that it seems that the tiffile is not saving correctly into my original ImageField. How can I fix this?

Comment: You are missing `upload_to` attribute of `ImageField` also overriding of save in model is wrong `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` is kept at last and `img.save()` is not needed i think you can move that save logic in your view

Comment: My upload_to is routed to a specific "Media" folder. How exactly do I save to the Django ImageField model, if I don't use img.save()?

Comment: Take a look here: https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10597/

Comment: I tried implementing that way, but I run into an attribute error. I think the error arises in that I'm trying to fill a image field while things have not totally uploaded?